# Why floated items take up extra space unneccesarily?

Tags: css, css-float

As you can see in the following snippet, after I remove an element with `parent.removeChild()`, the next floated `div` stays in its previous position while I would expect it to take up the newly freed space (where the previous sibling was)

[image]

And here's the CSS part if it helps:

```
.parent
            {
                margin: 5px;
                white-space: normal;
                overflow: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
                position: relative;
                vertical-align: top; /* default is "baseline" */
                display: inline-block;
                width: calc(var(--distance-between-packages) + var(--containers-width));
            }

.child
            {
                margin: calc(var(--distance-between-packages) / 2);
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border: 1px solid black;
                float: left;
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your html and javascript code  or make a reproducible example ? Thanks

Comment: can you put `css` too?

Comment: here it is; the CSS part that I've put up there